# Compiling tensorflow from source: Undefined reference to tensorflow::functor::FillFunctor

Tags: tensorflow

When compiling tensorflow from source with GPU support I get:

```
bazel build -c opt --config=cuda --verbose_failures //tensorflow/cc:tutorials_example_trainer
WARNING: Output base '/auto/homes/.cache/bazel/_bazel_/bd4752ce1a89280ab0ba7ef21866f7b1' is on NFS. This may lead to surprising failures and undetermined behavior.
WARNING: Sandboxed execution is not supported on your system and thus hermeticity of actions cannot be guaranteed. See http://bazel.io/docs/bazel-user-manual.html#sandboxing for more information. You can turn off this warning via --ignore_unsupported_sandboxing.
INFO: Found 1 target...
INFO: From Linking tensorflow/cc/tutorials_example_trainer:
bazel-out/local_linux-opt/bin/tensorflow/core/libkernels.lo(constant_op.o): In function `tensorflow::ZerosLikeOp<Eigen::GpuDevice, bool>::Compute(tensorflow::OpKernelContext*)':
constant_op.cc:(.text._ZN10tensorflow11ZerosLikeOpIN5Eigen9GpuDeviceEbE7ComputeEPNS_15OpKernelContextE[_ZN10tensorflow11ZerosLikeOpIN5Eigen9GpuDeviceEbE7ComputeEPNS_15OpKernelContextE]+0x181): undefined reference to `tensorflow::functor::FillFunctor<Eigen::GpuDevice, bool>::operator()(Eigen::GpuDevice const&, Eigen::TensorMap<Eigen::Tensor<bool, 1, 1, long>, 16>, Eigen::TensorMap<Eigen::TensorFixedSize<bool const, Eigen::Sizes<>, 1, long>, 16>)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've tried different bazel versions (0.1.1 and 0.1.4) but I get the same error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what caused the problem, but upgrading from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 removed it.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely due to having an old version of the c compiler. By upgrading your Ubuntu, you've also also upgraded the gcc, which allows TensorFlow to build with bazel.

For those who cannot upgrade the compiler, you can try with a local gcc, see here:
https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/649